# I have a trouble with MapMarker in MapView

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy_garden.mapview import MapView, MapMarker
from kivy.app import App

class MapViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        map = MapView(zoom=11, lat=50.6394, lon=3.057, double_tap_zoom=True)
        marker_1 = MapMarker(lon=50.6394, lat=3.057)
        map.add_marker(marker_1)
        return map

MapViewApp().run()
```

While using this code I get a white square instead of marker.
How can I get Google's map marker (shown below)?

[image: Google's map marker]

Answer (score 0):

You have your `lat` and `lon` mixed up in your marker. Try changing:

```
marker_1 = MapMarker(lon=50.6394, lat=3.057)
```

to:

```
marker_1 = MapMarker(lat=50.6394, lon=3.057)
```

To use your own marker graphic, use:

```
marker_1 = MapMarker(lat=50.6394, lon=3.057, source='marker.png')
```

where `marker.png` is whatever marker you want to use.

Comment: Updated my answer to include that info.

Comment: THANK YOU ! have a nice day )